# Can You Annotate with geom_bar (not based on a particular bar)

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
war_total %>%
  filter(Year == 2018) %>%
  top_n(60, wt = WAR) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(Player, -WAR), WAR, fill = Position))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = .7)+
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = mycolors,
    limits = names(mycolors)
  )+
  geom_vline(xintercept=which(war18$Player == 'Antonio Brown' | war18$Player ==  "O.J. Howard" | war18$Player ==  "Greg Zuerlein" | war18$Player ==  "Los Angeles Rams" |war18$Player == "Rob Gronkowski"))+
  theme_classic()+
    theme(text = element_text(size=8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))+
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
    ggtitle("2018")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))`
```

I ordered 60 individual geom_bar factors and want to annotate 5 chunks on top of the bars so that each of the 5 annotations group the bars in 12s. So for example, annotation "Round 1" will go over the first 12 bars, "Round 2" over the next 12 bars etc. Everything I see online either references a particular bar to associate the placement of the annotation with. I want to do it more free flowing.

Basically on the x axis is a bunch of NFL player names. I already created a vertical line every 12th player on the x axis manually and I'd just like the annotation to go above the bars for each group of 12.

Comment: Can you give an idea of what you want along with some data? I would assume a transformation function in the data argument could do the trick

Comment: It will help if you can draw what you have in mind and share an example of what you've tried.  I'd probably approach this by making a summary data frame describing the start and end of each section, the height of the annotation, and the label, and then map that to `geom_rect` or `gem_segment` plus `geom_text`.

Comment: OK I gave my ggplot code and tried to explain the data enough to have an idea